# Почему программа на языке c++ всегда выполняется за разное количество времени?

Tags: c++, opencv, realtime

Есть простейшая программа - захват картинки с камеры, обработка фильтром Canny, вывод итогового изображения:

```
int main()
{
double all_time;
VideoCapture cap1(0);
Mat img1, dst;

while (1) {
    all_time = (double)getTickCount();
    cap1 >> img1;
    Canny(img1, dst, 35, 200, 3);
    all_time = ((double)getTickCount() - all_time) * 1000 /getTickFrequency();
    cout<<"All time: "<<all_time<<"ms"<<endl;
    imshow("LIVE", dst);
    if (waitKey(30) > 0)
    {
        break;
    }
}
}
```

В консоли смотрю затраченное время:

```
All time: 30.3985ms
All time: 4.3556ms
All time: 9.03812ms
All time: 13.0144ms
All time: 7.4514ms
All time: 7.08991ms
All time: 7.96794ms
All time: 5.41924ms
All time: 6.22192ms
All time: 8.63754ms
All time: 7.19404ms
All time: 6.28379ms
All time: 14.7142ms
```

Отсюда возникает вопрос - почему выполнение одной и той же программы всегда занимает разный промежуток времени?

P.S. Язык программирования С++, использую библиотеку OpenCV.

Comment: А если сделать Canny 100 раз?

Comment: Да, на одном. Я, собственно, к тому веду, что измерение малых промежутков времени с помощью getTickCount vможет давать сомнительные результаты

Comment: @MBo запустил Canny на одном кадре 10 раз, получил такой же результат.

Comment: for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {Canny(img1, dst, 35, 200, 3);}

Comment: @MBo так и сделал, или ты предлагаешь измерить время за 100 раз?

Comment: Я сомневаюсь, что Canny будет работать существенно разное время на похожих кадрах (большинство шагов алгоритма занимает одно и тоже время для для данного размера), поэтому подозреваю, что первым шагом должно быть точное измерение

Comment: @MBo при зацикливании фильтра Canny 100 раз получаю: All time: 613.954ms All time: 506.141ms All time: 348.68ms All time: 357.18ms All time: 439.526ms All time: 397.049ms All time: 391.564ms All time: 442.276ms All time: 398.832ms

Comment: Ну вот уже разница в 1.7 раза, а не в 5  - это более реальный результат.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76022/discussion-between-denis-and-mbo).

Comment: Программа одинаковая, обрабатываемые данные разные. Программа одинаковая, загрузка процессора и необходимой периферии (диск) разная. Итд.

Comment: @Эникейщик, в таком случае есть ли возможность установить приоритетность программы чтобы она работа всегда одинаковое количество времени(минимальное)?

Comment: Да наверняка есть, но ничего конкретного сказать по этому поводу не могу.